# How to create a dotnet core single executable

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like to configure my dotnet core project to compile as a single executable.

The project is similar to the one generated with `dotnet new`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
     "win10-x64": {}
   }
}
```

How can I make it so this compiles as a single program.exe? When I run `dotnet publish` it puts dlls and the program.exe in a publish folder, but doesn't combine them.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it's not possible, why do you want to do that ?

Comment: make it easier to deploy a command line application - just one file

Comment: I also do not believe this is possible. If you're looking for a simple way to deploy as a single executable, you could just wrap your published files in an executable zip file- which would give you your single exe.

Comment: Besides  CoreRT you can use BoxedApp packer. This packer can pack all dependencies in one executable file. So, you can pack your dotnet core project into exe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest to answer is probably [`CoreRT`](https://github.com/dotnet/corert) (`.Net Core` to Native). It will be excellent fit but exist small problem - This project is still in early apha. A year ago they showed us demo but it was a very simple example and for more advanced projects will not work. Some more information [how to try do this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/crossgen.md).

Comment: The current state of CoreRT supports quite complex applications. It is definitely worth taking a look at it. It is also quite easy to get started.

Answer (score 5):

This is available as of .Net Core 3 like:

`dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true`

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables