# How to build an exe in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, .net, rider

I've just installed Rider for educational purposes. I'm going to develop on .NET Framework for Windows on Mac. Created a basic project. I'm trying to build an exe, but it building only dll and Mac binary. What I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

[image: configuration]

[image: application]

Comment: Maybe there is another problem. Could you please try building your exe from command line? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe

Comment: If I use the "publish" command, it builds dll+exe, and exe cannot run without dll :(

Comment: I did not catch what is your point? Do you want to create single exe file without dll?
If "yes" this may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153226/how-to-create-a-dotnet-core-single-executable

Comment: Could you tell me one more thing? Can I build for .NET Framework on Mac? As I understand it, if I want to build on *nix, I need Core, but not all users have it. Maybe with Docker? I see only one variant - a virtual machine.

Comment: AFAIK, You just need to have specific .net version installed on that platform. So your console app can run on that platform.

So IMHO if you can run "dotnet run" command on the platform it is all yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254087/discussion-between-megabomber-and-ozan-bayram).

Comment: sorry mate do not have time for chat.

Comment: no problem! thanks anyway! I just wanted one more question...

Is somewhere statistic about .NET versions usage? I want to know from which .NET I should start to run on 10/11 win without additional movements from users...
I've checked out a version on my win10 that I installed from the original MS image. I have 4.0. But development on 4.0 it's a pain...

Comment: I do not have any statistics but latest is 7 and recommended, It will be better as early as possible to move newer ones to not have bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on your project and there is an option `publish`, click it and select the target runtime and there is a checkbox `produce single file` (check it) and click run.
[image: publish context menu option after right clicking on project]
[image: produce single file checkbox in the following menu]